# Шрифт на странице норм поведения отличается от оригинального

Tags: дефект, дизайн, нормы-поведения

На странице [норм поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct) используется какой-то другой шрифт, нежели был в оригинале.

- [английский](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) (оригинал)

> [image: enso]

- [русский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct)

> [image: ruso]

- [испанский](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct) (для сравнения)

> [image: esso]

Comment: В заголовках или в тексте?

Comment: Вероятно, в используемом шрифте просто нет кириллицы...

Comment: @PavelMayorov заголовок и подзаголовок как минимум

Comment: @Qwertiy похоже что шрифтом она поддерживается, но не включена в файл шрифта

Answer (score 3):

Вообще, в оригинальном шрифте есть кириллица: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Slab

Но на SO почему-то используют [версию](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Fonts/roboto-slab/roboto-slab-bold-webfont.woff?v=719d1c709127) без кириллицы.

Задал [вопрос](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314190/260198) на MSE.

Comment: Может стоит вынести вопрос на MSE?

Comment: @alexolut хорошая идея. После обеда напишу там вопрос.

Comment: Приятного аппетита! :-D

Comment: @alexolut спс. Вопрос задал https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314190/260198

Comment: Какой быстрый обед, однако!

Comment: @alexolut предпочёл сначала с делами разобраться. А обед ещё нужно приготовить)