# Нормаму, я пришёл договориться

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, нормы-поведения

На странице правил поведения (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct) ошибка.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно оставить как есть. До туда никто не дочитывает.

Comment: @alexolut *никто не читает CoC.

Comment: А [шрифт](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7660/176217) так и не починили. Точнее, просто заменили на какой-то другой.

Comment: @alexolut и_так_сойдёт.jpg

Comment: @alexolut и где его заменили-то? Все тот же обрезанный Roboto Slab...

Comment: @PavelMayorov сравните картинки из моего поста с тем, что реально сейчас на сайте. Хотя, может здесь браузер вносит свои ограничения. У меня [вот так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7z5L.png) (слева старое, справа текущее).

Comment: @alexolut интересно о_О

Comment: @alexolut у меня такого не наблюдается. Кажется, у вас какой-то особенный браузер...

Comment: @PavelMayorov хм-м. Действительно. В FF и Chrome (под виндой) у меня почему-то разные шрифты. Номинальные картинки, вроде бы, вовсе на iPad делал в Chrome.

Comment: Текущее название вопроса никак не отражает его суть. Добавьте хотя бы в скобках нормальное название.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ключ: `ecc3044064b93d8f59049959f55ccd60`. Добавил предложение в транс.

Нужно, чтоб кто-нибудь заапрувил.

Comment: Заапрупрувивил.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ждём теперь, когда выкатят)

Comment: @Suvitruf сначала надо дёрнуть ещё.

Comment: @alexolut вроде дёрнули и обновилось, но ваша правка по дефисам, судя по всему, не выкатилась https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8105/15479.

Comment: Видимо, дергали до обновления