# С нормами поведения что—то не так

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, нормы-поведения

На странице [норм поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct) в слове «что‐то» вместо дефиса используется короткое тире. На это невозможно смотреть без боли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предлагаю заменить его на дефис, чтобы выглядело так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Возможно это тема для отдельного вопроса, но «или персональных *нападков*» тоже лучше исправить.

Comment: Пора Доктора вызывать. А то уже опасно!

Comment: Пофикшено. С нюансами.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дефис организовал. Фразу про нападки подкорректировал:

> No name-calling or personal attacks.
>   Никаких оскорблений или личных выпадов.

Появится на сайте после череды обновлений.

Comment: Принял ответ, спасибо! Только в результате там появился минус, а не дефис. Дефис выглядит лучше: [сравните](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmuVN.png) (дефис снизу).

Comment: @defaultlocale всегда использовал тот же символ, что и сейчас, если честно. В той строке, кажется, что-то со стилями.

Comment: Да, я тоже в тексте вопроса сначала поставил минус. Как правило он смотрится нормально, но в полужирном Roboto выделяется. Но, в принципе, это не так критично.